# hammerjs gestures not working on angular version 11?

Tags: angular, version, hammer.js

I've been trying to setup hammerjs for simple swipe gestures, it's been now 2 days that I can not set it up, and I can't even find some sources to get it done.
I am confused if Angular is supporting hammerjs?

Acording to thise source: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/HammerGestureConfig, there are still some configurations for hammerjs implemented in Angular!

Any advice for Angular version 11.2.8 is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `HammerModule` to your `app.module.ts` imports

```
import { HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HammerModule
  ],
})
```

This was my issue. Apparently, this is required since version 9 but I updated it from 8 to 11